# Showing the 20 first instances of this Tag model in an index view of this other Post model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a **Post** and **Tag** model.

I would like to show the first 20 instances of the **Tag** model in the index view of the **Post** model.

(Pretty much what you see in StackOverflow's home page in the sidebar).

What's the best way of doing this?

(by the way, I'm using `will_paginate`)

**EDIT:**

I tried adding `render 'tags/index` in the posts index view, created a `index.html.erb` file in `views/tags`.

But I'm getting this:

> Showing /home/alex/rails/r18/app/views/layouts/_sidebar.html.erb where
>   line #14 raised:
>
> Missing partial tags/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html],
>   :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:   *
>   "/home/alex/rails/r18/app/views"   *
>   "/home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/ckeditor-3.7.0.rc3/app/views"
>   * "/home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-2.0.4/app/views"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first or the most recent?

```
 # in your post index controller action
@tags= Tag.limit(20).order("ID asc")

# in your view 
<% @tags.each do |tag| %>
  <%= tag.name %>
<% end %>
```

Shows the first 20 tags.